# Is there a way to close all ports using iOS

Tags: network, internet-sharing

Is the a way I can block the use of all apple devices in my network either thru router or my fing box specifically iphone and apple watch

Comment: Are you looking for ways to control your router from an iOS device, for ways to prevent iOS devices from accessing the router itself, for ways to prevent iOS devices from accessing the internet, or something else altogether? Please add details to your question by editing it.

Comment: Also, unless you are using an Airport/Time Capsule as a router questions about how to configure a router are better asked on https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a "Parental control" option in your router, from where you can set up rules for access.

You don't mention any specific router brand, so I can't give you a specific how-to.